# Nativescript App will run but not debug?

Tags: nativescript

I have a Nativescript app which I have been developing fine on windows with an Android simulator. I have just moved over to my mac, to try out my app on ios.

The app will deploy to a device with the `tns run ios` command, but if I run `tns debug ios`, I get an error:

> [31;1mTimeout waiting for response from NativeScript runtime.
>
> Command failed: The debug process exited unexpectedly code:127

`tns doctor` doesn't show any issues.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that such an issue has been reported in this github issue [1620](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1620).
Another option if your are using `http / https` requests in your app `tns debug ios` could lead to error.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I just saw in my related--did you try increasing the timeout?

The help docs say it defaults to 90 seconds, but doesn't seem to really work that way. Whenever I debug I almost always set the timeout to 5 minutes by adding: --timeout=300